# Duplicate symbol error when linking AdMob SDK in RubyMotion

Tags: ios, rubymotion

My RubyMotion project builds fine, but fails at the linking stage, specifically when linking against `GoogleAdMobAds`, with a "duplicate symbol" error:

```
Compile ./app/controllers/blahblah_view_controller.rb
# compiling here, everything is awesome, until...    
Create ./build/iPhoneOS-6.1-Development/App.app
Link ./build/iPhoneOS-6.1-Development/App.app/APP
duplicate symbol _GAD_MD5 in:
  /Users/edd/Projects/ProjectName/vendor/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(md5.o)
  /Users/edd/Projects/ProjectName/vendor/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(gad_md5.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer...]
  /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:393:in `build'
  /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/app.rb:72:in `build'
  /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => build:device
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It's worth noting this occurs *only when building for device*. It works fine running in the simulator. Relevant `Rakefile` line:

```
app.vendor_project('vendor/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK', :static)
```

This problem also occurs when including the SDK via CocoaPods.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After perusing support forums for Google's AdMob, I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/yfQbiqzLfdA/AXGOsgG9z9AJ) basically saying issues have been observed when linking against the AdMob SDK when passing the `-force_load` flag to `ld`. Nobody goes into any more detail than that, but whatever.

Browsing the source, I also found an undocumented config option for RubyMotion's `vendor_project` that can make its invocation of `ld` use simply `-ObjC` instead of `-force_load` for your vendored code, and apparently that's what was needed to make this compile for me:

```
app.vendor_project('vendor/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK', :static, force_load: false)
```

Voila. I unfortunately can't explain why this is only happening when building for a device (probably something to do with `-force_load` combining with arch flags somewhere deep in RubyMotion), so if anyone can offer any wisdom, please leave a comment here.

Comment: force_load forces the compiler to include every single object from the specified library. AdModSDK has a duplicate object, which conflicts with the system library (probably), and the compiler pointed that. If you don't use force_load, categories might not be loaded from AdModSDK. Your app will crash when AdModSDK uses them. The force_load flag only works on 64bit OSX or iOS apps and that's why it works on the simulator (32 bits).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use -force_load (too much conflicts on the project with -ObjC for example) you can do the following.

- Get a hexa editor (0xED for example)
- Open the static lib with it
- Go to the last line
- Change the name of the constant to something else
- save
- done!